# Bash command fails with bash -c but works in an interactive shell

Tags: bash, io-redirection, quoting, subshell

I have this *fairly* simple command that, when ran inside bash, outputs the remaining disk space to `stdout`:

```
echo -n "External1TB: $(grep -Poi '(\/mnt\/External1TB\s+)\K(.*)' <(df -H --output=target,avail))B"
```

I'm using process redirection `<()` to pipe the output of `df` to `grep`, which then processes the output and filters out just the remaining space. All of that is wrapped inside a subshell `$()` and fed to `echo` so I can prepend the output with a disk name.

Example output: `External1TB: 882GB`

It works fairly well when ran inside an interactive bash shell, however if I try to run it using `bash -c`, like so:

```
bash -c "echo -n "External1TB: $(grep -Poi '(\/mnt\/External1TB\s+)\K(.*)' <(df -H --output=target,avail))B"",
```

the output is always: `External1TB:`. It seems that either `grep` or `df` fail for some reason.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quoting for the inner part needs to be escaped:

```
bash -c "echo -n \"External1TB: $(grep -Poi '(\/mnt\/External1TB\s+)\K(.*)' <(df -H --output=target,avail))B\"",
```

Alternatively, consider putting at least parts of this into a function or a script so that you don't need to stack string escaping upon string escaping.